# Picture after the text but in the mobile view above the text

Tags: html, css, sass

Is it possible that the picture is on the right and the text is on the left in the lower box, but on the mobile itself the picture is above the text?

[image]

I know if I were to create the image (img) after the text (p) in my HTML code, the image would be on the right, but on the mobile view the text is above the image.

HTML:

```
 <div class="box-mission">
        <div class="flex-row middle-sm">
            <div class="flex-col-sm-5 flex-col-xs-12">
                <img src="https://pickaface.net/gallery/avatar/unr_test_161024_0535_9lih90.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flex-col-sm-7 flex-col-xs-12">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-mission">
        <div class="flex-row middle-sm">
            <figure class="flex-col-sm-5 flex-col-xs-12">
                <img src="https://pickaface.net/gallery/avatar/unr_test_180711_1752_p1n69px.png">
            </figure>
            <div class="flex-col-sm-7 flex-col-xs-12">
                <h3>consetetur sadipscing elitr,</h3>
                <p>aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                    kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-mission {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px -3px #32435f;
}
```

I use:
bootstrap: 3.4.1,
laravel: 6.0

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: I think you need to use media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use bootstrap 3.4.1, You most use push and pull on breakpoints like this:
[bootstrap 3 document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-column-ordering)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-push-3" style="background:red; height:100px"></div> 
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-pull-9" style="background:blue; height:100px"></div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Amirrr1987/pen/porVbGO)